# The NodeJs API working fine on Thunder Client but not working after integration in flutter

Tags: flutter, nodejs-server

I have created my SignUp API in NodeJs and its working fine when I try to run on thunder client but when I try to integrate in flutter it doesn't work. I have worked before with the same API and same code in flutter the similar code but the error coming up in the recent one. I don't know where's the issue coming up this is the issue come when I try to press SignUp button.

[image: error]

Here's the NodeJs API,

[image]

and here's the flutter integration

[image]

and here is the rest of the code of SignUp page in flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:order_eats/APIS/user_api.dart';
import 'package:order_eats/screens/auth_screens/login.dart';
import 'package:order_eats/screens/auth_screens/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:order_eats/screens/auth_screens/widgets/custom_field.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUp({super.key});

  static const routeName = '/signup';

  @override
  State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void userSignup() {
    UserApis().userSignUP(context, emailController.text,
        passwordController.text, nameController.text);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Order Eats',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 97, 164, 1)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Lets get started',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  CustomField(name: 'Name', controller: nameController),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  CustomField(
                    name: 'Email',
                    controller: emailController,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  CustomField(name: 'Password', controller: passwordController),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  CustomButton(
                      ontap: () {
                        if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          userSignup();
                        }
                      },
                      text: 'Sign Up'),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Already have an account? ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(LoginScreen.routeName),
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 97, 164, 1),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's because you're making a request to `/user/signup`, while the endpoint in NodeJS is `/api/signup`, Am I missing something?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I-Never convert your API body data to JSON using jsonEncode in Flutter. This is unnecessary and can lead to issues.
II-Always enclose your API body data within { } brackets. This is the correct format for data sent in the body of an API request.
III-Include key-value pairs within the brackets:

```
body: {
  'Key1': 'Value1',
  'Key2': 'Value2',
  // ...other key-value pairs
},
```

By following these steps, you can avoid common mistakes and ensure smooth API integration in your Flutter app.

I hope this revised message is clearer and more helpful!